Chilkat error: package com.chilkatsoft does not exist
I'm trying to import Chilkat Java (jar and dll) files to Intellij Gradle Project.
I did follow the instructions, but after importing package can be found by IDE, but when run the appliction I got this message "error: package com.chilkatsoft does not exist".
What is the reason?

Looks like the "build" path includes the relevant JAR (and DLL) files but the "runtime" path does not.
